# excel, extract unique values from one column based on the relationship between two columns

Tags: excel

I have a list of users and their session ID's.  I need to extract the unique session ID's for each user using preferably a formula.

I have placed a simplified image of what I am trying to achieve below.

I have tried the following array... but it doesn't limit the output to a specific user...

```
{=INDEX(session_ids, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, session_ids),0))}
```

[image]

If anyone has any knowlege of the portion of the formula that I am missing, any help would be greatful!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is not considering the username. You need to filter session ids matching username.

```
=INDEX(IF(user_id="user2",session_ids,""), MATCH(0, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, IF(user_id="user2",session_ids,"")),0))
```

**EDIT**

OP's solution is better than what I came up with as it avoids creatting a filtered array which is done by the IF function (twice) in my formula. Here is the more efficient formula modified slightly in for consistency with my formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(session_ids, MATCH(0, IF(user_id="user2", COUNTIF(D$1:D1, session_ids)),0)),"")
```

Comment: how does this compare with another solution I came up with just a little bit ago?
`=IFERROR(INDEX(session_ids, MATCH(0, IF(user_id=E1, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, session_ids)),0)),"")`
is there one that is particularly better at processing? or might one of the two have a chance for error?

Comment: I missed that. Yours is better and will process faster!

Comment: can you update your answer with my formula as an alternate way of producing the answer.  I want to give the points to you for all of your help and for the information on processing